# How to get "Oh, That's How You Do It" achievement?

Tags: achievements, payday-2

Now I've gone through my share of Payday 2 achievements. However,there are still a few achievements which have got me stumped. In this case, it's the **"Oh, That’s How You Do It"**. Essentially, you have to:

> Fire the Vulcan Minigun for **25 seconds** without reloading or letting go
>   of the trigger.

I have tried this several times. With a full magazine, when I just hold down the mouse button, it only fires for about 20 seconds thereabouts. In addition, there are no mods that can lower its rate of fire or increase its magazine capacity.

**Is this achievement a troll? I really do not want to waste my time on it if it was.**

Note: I play on the PC not the console versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the Enforcer skill [Bullet Storm](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Bullet_Storm) (Ace).

[image: bullet storm]

It allows you to fire without depleting your ammunition for 15 seconds directly after deploying an ammo bag.

Comment: The skill will initially give you 5 seconds of unlimited ammunition, so if you already have 20 seconds, you should be right. The tier 3 level of this skill gives you an extra 10.

Comment: @Timelord64 He said *about 20 seconds*, which might well be a little less. And the wiki explicitely states that the achievement "can only be done if one has maxed out Bullet Storm".

Comment: And the first person who tried over and over again and then finally figured it out and earned the achievement very likely said "Oh!  So that's how you do it!" :)

Comment: Oh! So that's how you do it!